# Xdebug debugging not working on Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, xdebug

I'm having a problem with [Xdebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdebug) not working with [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 3. The server I've used is wampserver. I have use the Xdebug wizard for which version I'm supposed to install. Here's the picture:

[image: Xdebug installation instruction]

Here's the phpinfo for Xdebug:

[image: Here's the phpinfo]

Here's where the Xdebug extension is for Xdebug in php.ini:

```
    ; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="P:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.4\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="P:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

I've tried Xdebug sublime settings in Sublime Text like

[image]

when I tried testing my PHP code, and it still didn't do anything.

I follow the website https://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-xdebug-sublime-text-3/ for configuring Xdebug, and it still didn't work at all.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173485/xdebug-does-not-break-on-breakpoints-from-atoms-php-debug-package

Answer (score 2):

In sublime settings you need a real url (you've put there a folder path).

You need something like:
`"url": "dev.myproject.com"`

---

You can create you virtual host (at least in WampServer) directly from the main page of the Server (localhost - if you haven't override it - should give you the main configuration)[image]

---

In php.ini, besides other xdebug attributes, I found that I need the following activated in order for everything to work:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
```

---

Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 1):

Check sublime terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>). If it shows an error like, "`xdebug xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)`," then it is issue of sublime xdebug client installed through sublime package manager.

1. Uninstall xdebug client installed through Package manager:
   Preferences > Package control > remove package > xdebug client
2. Quit sublime
3. Install client manually through source code:
   Get fixed source code of xdebug client from [GitHub: SublimeTextXdebug](https://github.com/gepeixoto/SublimeTextXdebug.git).

   - Download source code (do not follow install instructions, just download raw source code)
   - Copy source code directory to sublime packages directory. In mac it is here
     /users/[username]/library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/